When is a Function a Flow
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a continuous injective function.  Is there a way to verify if $f$ is a flow of a time homogeneous ODE?  That is, if there is a Lipschitz time independent vector field $V:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $f(x)=\Phi_V(1,x)$ where
$$
\dot{\Phi}(t,x) = V(\Phi(t,x)) \mbox{ and } \Phi(0,x)=x.
$$

Do you want to assume that $V$ is Lipschitz, so we can apply existence and uniqueness to construct a local flow?

Hey, yes of course:)

Just to state the (almost) obvious: There are of course many maps that can not be embedded in flows. (I very much doubt there can be a useful general criterion.) An example is given by the map $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ on $\mathbb R^2$. The reason is simple: Since a flow $\phi_t$ with $\phi_1=f$ would commute with $f$, it must also leave ${ (x,x)}$ invariant, so we won't be able to get from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ since we would have to cross the diagonal. See also my old question (and YCor's answer) here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269004/can-the-full-shift-be-embedded-in-a-flow

Perhaps Prof. Rugh's answer might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425648/invariant-curves-induce-invariant-regions-in-discrete-2d-dynamical-systems
